# GEE and post hoc comparisons

Tags: r, post-hoc, generalized-estimating-equations

I am trying to analyze a dataset using the GEE.

This is what I have so far

```
C=read.table("Cnarinofinal4.txt",header=T)
attach(C)
names(C)
library(geepack)
Form <-  formula(Conteo~Grupo+Tiempo+Comportamiento+Comportamiento*Grupo+Comportamiento*Hora)
M4 <- geeglm(Form,family = poisson, id =Individuo, corstr = "exchangeable")
anova(M4)
```

I want to know how to perform post hoc comparisons for significant terms, in this case I have a significant result for the interaction Comportamiento*Hora and the factor Comportamiento. I know the post hoc comparisons must be done using the package `multicomp` and probably by hand, but if someone has an example, it would be really useful.

Since I cannot attach the dataset (it has about 6000 data) I am attaching a picture to show what it looks like.

http://postimg.org/image/luyyoovej/63f4d80c/

Comment: If this is just a request for R code, sorry, but it is off-topic here. If there is uncertainty about what should be done statistically, please make it the focus of your question.

Comment: Not really, I want to know how to compare this using the R software and what is the principle behind this. Unfortunately there is not much info about GEE and R, so if any of you could provide an example, it would be great.

Comment: "What is the principle behind this?" is a statistical question but still too vague to be a good question.

Comment: I need to know how to make a posthoc comparison when using GEE. That´s it